# How to show success message after the form submit is successful

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP.NET MVC. After the form submission, I want to display a success message with partial view under the submit button on main view.

```
<form action="myactionLInk" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter name here..."/>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

// Here would be some code to load partialview
<div>
   @Html.Partial("_userpartial")
</div>
```

Here is my `UserContoller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult userData(FormCollection collection)
{
    //Save name, email and contact to ViewBag
    return PartialView("_userPartial")
}
```

Here is `_userPartial.cshtml`:

```
<p> Data of @Viewbag.Name successfully saved.</p>
```

I want the partial view to be loaded under the submit button on successful creation. I am still learning MVC so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need partial view to show this success message? you can do simply as follows:

**As you said your very new to ASP.NET MVC, so here I am giving you a full solution to how you can show the success message after an entity creation.**

First write a model class follows:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public int UserName {get; set;}
}
```

Then in the `User` Controller:

```
public class UserController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateUser()
    {
         return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateUser(User user)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          // save the user here

          ViewBag.SuccessMessage = user.UserName + " has been created successfully!"
          ModelState.Clear();
          return View();
        }
        return View(user);
   }
}
```

Then in your `CreateUser.cshmtl` view:

```
@using User

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUser", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

@{
  if(ViewBag.SuccessMessage != null)
  {
     <div>
         @ViewBag.SuccessMessage
     </div>
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I am using a partial view because success message contains Name of the person and I may add more details later.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check this line `ViewBag.SuccessMessage = user.UserName + " has been created successfully!"`